# jquery, javascript and callback timing

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

```
var blah = Some.Thing(data, function(a,b) {
  // code here 
});

Some.Thing = function(data, callback) {

  if(...) {
     var a = Other.Thing(data, function() {
       // code here

        callback();
        return;
     });    
  }

  callback();
};
```

My question is, will the part that says `//code here` fire *only* after everything else and their callbacks fire?

The `//code here` part seems to fire, and there seems to be some timing issue.

Comment: With 4,485 rep, you don't know how to format code in a question?!

Comment: “Seems to fire”, “timing issue”... Can you be a bit more specific (by showing more parts of your code)?

Comment: Which of the two `// code here` parts? Everything is executed in sequential order, so when you put `// code here` above `callback();`, it will be executed *before* `callback`.

Comment: ok let me re-write this question properly!

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually using `callback` anywhere in `Some.Thing`, so it's impossible to say. But yes, generally, unless something actually *calls* `callback`, the code within it is not executed. It is evaluated (parsed), but not executed.

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible to tell from the code you supplied.
The method `callback` can either be called *while* on the same stack, or its execution might be *deferred* due to ajax or setTimeout being used (asynchronous).

If being deferred, then it would be called only after the main method has completed and the thread going back to idle.